# Shared Roles not appearing while joining a new server to an existing farm 2016.?

Tags: sharepoint-server, minrole

We had created a SharePoint 2016 farm using Minrole, before the release of Feature Pack 1. This farm contains 4 servers - one WebFrontEnd, Application, distributed cache and search server. For High Availability, we require to add shared roles with 2 more servers. 
We have now installed Feature Pack 1 and 2. However while joining a new server to this existing farm, I do not see the new shared roles such as WebFrontEndWithDistributedCache and ApplicationWithSearch. We need to add the new servers with shared roles. Could you suggest a solution for this issue..?

Answer (score 1):

Is FP2 installed on the new servers you have not yet joined? This would be a requirement.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/104961)

Comment: Yes, it does. You must install it on the new servers prior to joining the farm, which is what my answer indicated. Thanks.

Comment: As Trevor stated the new servers need to be on the same patch level / CU / FP as the existing farm, before you join them to the existing farm.

Comment: Three main points to note:

1) The original farm was created using SharePoint 2016 RTM. It was later updated with FP 1 and FP 2. 
2) A new server needed to be added to the Farm. This server was updated with FP 1 and FP 2 and then while attempting to join to the existing farm, it does not show the option of the new shared roles such as WebFrontEndWithDistributedCache and ApplicationWithSearch

Comment: 3)  If I go to the central admin of the existing farm, Under Change roles, I do see the default options of Web Front End, Distributed cache, Search Server, Application, Custom but not able to see "WebFrontEndWithDistributedCache" and "applicationWithSearch".

Comment: Did you complete the Config Wizard? Doesn't sound like you've properly updated the farm.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, for your continous update on this. We would like to clarify that we were able to run the config wizard without any issue.The only issue that we are facing now is not able to see the latest shared roles("WebFrontEndWithDistributedCache" and "applicationWithSearch") on the configuration wizard (We don't have any issue on viewing the other server roles).
Do you have an idea why we are not able to view those..?